# What is the meaning of the wave equation characteristic lines?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, characteristics

**Background**

I am self-studying *Introduction to PDEs* by Walter Strauss. In chapter 1, Strauss describes that the characteristic lines of the PDE

$$
au_x+bu_t=0
$$

are given by $bx-at=C$, and the function $u(x,t)$ is constant along these lines in xt space.

In chapter 2, Strauss shows that the wave equation, $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$ has two families of characteristic lines

$$
x+ct=C
$$
$$
x-ct=C
$$

and the general solution to the wave equation is
$$
u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)
$$

The families of characteristic lines are sketched here:
[image]

**Question**

What is an intuitive meaning of the two "families" $x\pm ct=C$ for the wave equation? If we consider $u$ on the line $x+ct=C$, is $u$ strictly constant?

$$\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=u\left(x,\frac{1}{c}(C-x)\right)=f(C)+g(2x-C)
\end{align}
$$

So it seems that $u(x,t)$ is not totally constant on the line $x+ct=C$, because the other wave can "pass over" and change the value. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I see. So, in a sense, we could express $u$ as an arbitrary number of waves of wave pulses, as long as those waves are either rightward or leftward running. And each of these pulses would be "information carriers". The total value of $u$ at any $(x,t)$ is the sum of the information from each wave. Would you agree with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariano's comment pointed me in the right direction, I believe.

The characteristic lines are "lines on which information can move". So, when $x+ct=C$ is constant, $f(x+ct)$ is constant, but $g(x-ct)$ is not. For a given time $t$, the x-value $x=C-ct$ is a particular point on the left-running wave $f(x+ct)$ with constant contribution to $u$.

Below, I visualize two Gaussian pulse solutions to the wave equation. One moves to the left, and one to the right. The black point on the left-running wave corresponds to $x+ct=1$. Note that $u(x,t)$ is not constant for $(1-ct,t)$.

[image]

I had some more time, so I decided to plot more points and visualize their path along the characteristic lines.

[image]